# XPath Selecting Certain Element

Tags: python, xpath

I've been trying for hours now to select a certain element, but can't seem to do it...

This is my code:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import sys
import re
import os

doc = etree.parse(open("patches.plist"))
for app_dict in doc.xpath('/plist/dict/array/dict'):
    for method_dict in app_dict.xpath('.//dict[key="overrides"]/array/dict'):
        for return_dict in method_dict.xpath('.//dict[key="overrides"]/array/dict'):
        returnValue = method_dict.xpath('//key[.="argument"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()')[0]
        print(returnValue)
```

This is what I am trying to select the element/get the value from, I've commented what I am trying to capture with `// THIS VALUE IS WHAT I WANT`

Link: 
https://ghostbin.com/paste/68ffu

Note: Some imports may not be needed, but ignore that. They are needed in other parts of the .py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import sys
import re
import os

doc = etree.parse(open("patches.plist"))
for app_dict in doc.xpath('//dict[key="subtype" and key="type"]/integer[preceding-sibling::key[text()="type"]]/text()'):
        print(app_dict)
```

I changed the position with predicate on value like you example. I used only one expression, by you can split it iy you need.

The whole expresion : `/plist/dict/array/dict/array/dict[key="overrides"]/array/dict[key="argument"]/dict[key="subtype" and key="type"]/integer[preceding-sibling::key[text()="type"]]/text()`

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick :

`/plist/dict/array/dict[1]/array/dict/array/dict[1]/dict[1]/integer[2]`

If you need to get the node value, add `/text()` at the end of the expression.

Regards,

Comment: Sorry, could you show me how to implement that in my code? Or just how to print it out? I'm new to XPath & Python.

Comment: I've been trying since you left, still no result... latest attempt: https://ghostbin.com/paste/fpo9e. Someone, please help.